# Type problem when including tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, tr1

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with Feature Pack 1.

I have a typedef like this `typedef std::tr1::tuple<std::string, std::string, int> tileInfo`
with a function like this `const tileInfo& GetTile( int x, int y ) const`.

In the implementation file the function has the exact same signature (with the added class name qualifier) and I am getting a `redefinition: different type modifiers` error. It seems to be looking for an `int&` instead of a `tileInfo&`

When I mouse over the type of the function in the header, i.e. `tileInfo&` it brings up a little bar saying `static const int tileInfo`. I think this may be the problem, but I'm not sure what to do. It leads me to believe that the compiler thinks `std::tr1::tuple<std::string, std::string, int>` is a `static const int`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

P.S. Here is an example emulating the same situation, just compacted to the minimum.

```
#include <tuple>

class Blah {
 public:
  typedef std::tr1::tuple<std::string, std::string, int> tileInfo;
  tileInfo& GetTile( int x, int y ); // When you mouse over tileInfo in this line, it says static const int
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when using the typedef as a return type or a local variable, even within the class, I had to qualify it with the class name as well. For example the `GetTile` signature in the header should have been `TileMap::tileInfo& GetTile( int x, int y );` I thought that you didn't need to do this when the function is in the class with the typedef.

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure you included header file with the `typedef`.**

It sounds like compiler can't see the `typedef` so the type of `tileInfo` defaults to `int`.

Comment: It is included. What I described last is actually showing up in the header. The function's signature is below the typedef in public visibility.

Comment: do you include `tuple` and `string` before you define typedef?

Comment: I think it may have something to do with me not installing the Feature Pack 1 correctly or something.

Comment: Is the typedef header included within the *header* that declares GetTile? Or just in the source file? If it thinks it's int within the header that leads me to believe it can't figure out what type it is.

Comment: yes it can't figure out what the type is, we're trying to imagine his code to figure out why ... might be easier if we've see some example code how is it organized ...